# What language was YouTube Android built in?

Tags: android, youtube

I am curious to know What language, framework, or library was YouTube for Android built in, Flutter, Java, or Kotlin?

Comment: This is not the right platform to ask this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very beginning the founders of YouTube used PHP. On acquisition by google, the core language was changed to Python. Google uses c++ and Java and it wouldn't be a surprise that this languages have been used for creating various APIs. And as you may be aware google have developed their own language 'GO' and it wouldn't be shock that they use it for some YouTube APIs. [https://www.freelancinggig.com/blog/2018/09/26/what-programming-language-is-youtube-written-in/]

Answer (score -1):

About most of youtube is written in python. I can't say which module, flutter or whatever, but I can say it's python. Some of the other important functions were written in c/c++. And some other things are written in java & javascript. This was all about the app (android/ios).

If talk about the web ([youtube.com](https://youtube.com)), it's written in all of these languages including html5.

There's lack of information about youtube's development, so these all are guesses of different people combined.

I hope it helped you understand all about the development of youtube.